# What is the missing binary operator before token "(" 44 | #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) GNU?

Tags: opencv, g++, cygwin, cross-compiling, arm64

I am getting the above error.
I work in cygwin 3.15 under windows 10. glibc 2.30 version included.
while compiling opencv project with aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ compiler with.
a snippet of error is

```
.... from constants.cpp:1:
/home/user/x-tools/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.2.0/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   44 | #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
```

where as simple c++ program is compiled without any error for the same target.

Comment: from where the compiler is coming from ? How you configured and run the compilation phase ?

Comment: Thanks for quick response...compiler built using crosstool-ng using sample configuration from crosstool-ng for aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu.

Comment: my guess is that `__GLIBC_PREREQ` was not declared before arriving on line 44. Check where is declared and if the `#include` chains are covering that header

Comment: Thanks to you Mr. Matzen. The issue resolved by removing include header file folder compile command option which erroneously chose /usr/local/include instead of the one under sysroot...

Comment: @MuruganSaivam, which option exactly was at fault there?